# markup.py how to use ':' in a tag

Tags: python, xml

**Code**:

```
import markup
url_= ('href1.com','href2.com')
mycxml=markup.page(mode='xml', case='given')
mycxml.init(encoding='utf-8')
mycxml.Collection.open()
mycxml.Items(url_)
mycxml.collection.close()
print mycxml
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Collection>
<Items>href1.com</Items>
<Items>href2.com</Items>
</collection>
```

I would like to have a line like `<Collection xmlns:p="somelines">` instead of `<Collection>`, but the `:` does not let me compile it. How can I "escape" it?

Comment: Umm... is "markup" part of openpyxl? I installed openpyxl and don't see any markup module.

Comment: They appear to be referring to this [markup.py](http://markup.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: you are right! i was just using openpyxl, and made a type, soz about that. :)

Comment: `markup.py` doesn't seem to support XML namespaces. Use a proper XML library like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) that [supports namespaces](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, will try it out, just searching for the right tool for it :)

Comment: actually i would like to be able to write CXML is there an special tool for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if markup.py has something built-in to handle this, but it's easy to force python to accept it using the `**` syntax:

```
import markup
url_= ('href1.com','href2.com')
mycxml=markup.page(mode='xml', case='given')
mycxml.init(encoding='utf-8')
mycxml.Collection(**{'xmlns:p': 'somelines'})
mycxml.Items(url_)
mycxml.collection.close()
print mycxml
```

output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Collection xmlns:p="somelines">
<Items>href1.com</Items>
<Items>href2.com</Items>
</collection>
```

Comment: Yeah, I looked through the markup.py source code. There's no more convenient alternative.